# Android FileOutputStream.write: got java.io.IOException: Math result not representable

Tags: android, math, ioexception

I got that "interesting" exception in my in-the-wild server errorlog. My app posts exceptions and "wtf"-errors to my central server, so I don't have much information what *exactly* happend. I just know THAT it happend, and I don't have any clue.

Stacktrace:

`java.io.IOException: Math result not representable
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.writeImpl(Native Method)
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.write(OSFileSystem.java:129)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:297)
        at net.jav.apps.romeolive.RomeoInterface.fetchBinaryToFile(RomeoInterface.java:299)
        at net.jav.apps.romeolive.HeartBeatService$_fetchPic.run(HeartBeatService.java:327)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)`

The code in place of net.jav.apps.romeolive.RomeoInterface:

```
    byte[] ret=fetchBinary(fullurl);

    if (ret==null) return false;

    try 
    {
        FileOutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(getCacheFileName(type,fullurl));
        os.write(ret, 0, ret.length);
```

The "failing" line #299 is the os.write()

fetchBinary(url) fetches some binary file (thumbnail jpg) from a web server and returns it as a byte[], or NULL if not found/error.

getCacheFileName(type,fullurl) returns the cacheDir() plus type plus the sanitized fullurl (removing slashes, only use the localpart of the url).

So what exactly fails, is... Trying to write the existing thumbnail jpg byte[] to a perfectly crafted filename in cacheDir().

The device where this exception showed up (ONCE only until now) is: GT-I9000@samsung/GT-I9000/GT-I9000/GT-I9000:2.2.1/FROYO/XXJPY:user/release-keys

Did anyone have this "Math result not representable" as IOException?
I'd really like to nail down that thing ;) Google and Stackoverflow didn't show up anything helpful or even related.

Thanks a lot,
Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me like this could be a bug in your code, but I can't be sure of that.

The string "Math result not representable" shows up in Google searches as being associated with ERRNO 34 (ERANGE), which is also represented with the string "Numerical result out of range".

The [source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/libcore.git;a=blob;f=luni/src/main/native/org_apache_harmony_luni_platform_OSFileSystem.cpp;h=31007670a92fdfae6f8ceaa5242a53bb1963e160;hb=refs/heads/froyo-plus-aosp) for org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.writeImpl is:

```
static jlong harmony_io_writeImpl(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jint fd,
        jbyteArray byteArray, jint offset, jint nbytes) {

    jbyte* bytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(byteArray, NULL);
    jlong result = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(write(fd, bytes + offset, nbytes));
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(byteArray, bytes, JNI_ABORT);

    if (result == -1) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN) {
            jniThrowException(env, "java/io/InterruptedIOException",
                    "Write timed out");
        } else {
            jniThrowIOException(env, errno);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So any random system error during the write will percolate back up to Java as an IOException, including ERANGE. But I don't see where a range error could have happened; the [man page for write(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) doesn't list ERANGE as one of its possible error codes.

Comment: I found another manpage to write(2), which has ERANGE listed ;) ->      ERANGE              fd refers to a stream, the total  number
                         of  bytes  to  be written is outside the
                         minimum and maximum write range, and the
                         minimum value is non-zero.
... still doesnt make any sense to me...

Comment: Reading my comment again... Makes me think... "the minimum value is non-zero"... Did I try to write 0 bytes (server REALLY sent 0 bytes to me)? Gonna try what happens in that case... *try* no exception :-(

Comment: I think passing a count value of 0 into write() is legal. It makes sense that it would be, as a way of checking the file status. From the man page (one of them, anyway :-) : "If count is zero and fd refers to a regular file, then write() may return a failure status if one of the errors below is detected.  If no errors are detected, 0 will be returned without causing any other effect.  If count is zero and fd refers to a file other than a regular file, the results are not specified."

Comment: Also, if you're writing to a file, then you're not writing to a stream (in the Unix sense of the word, not the Java sense), so that description for ERANGE doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and comments. I guess I just will put this thing into the "wtf did android do here?" category and don't think about it anymore ;)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a bug only on Samsung devices.